# HC05 and ELM327 NODATA sending PID codes

Tags: bluetooth, hc-05, pid

I am working on a project where I am using an HC05 connected to an Arduino to connect to an ELM327 Bluetooth scanner. I am using the SoftwareSerial Arduino library to send and read information from and too the HC05 using the following code. However when I use this code to send PID codes to the HC05 to request data such as 010C I am almost always receiving `010CNODATA>`.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(9, 10);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(38400);
}

void loop(){
  if (mySerial.available()){
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()){
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
```

My wiring for the HC05 is:

- EN: No connection
- VCC: Arduino 5v
- GND: Arduino Ground
- TXD: Digital Pin 9
- RXD: Digital Pin 10
- STATE: No connection

I have verified that I am linked to the ELM327 device as I do receive the NODATA from the device. I have ensured that the Arduino Serial monitor is in the 'both NL and CR' mode as that is the data format that the HC05 and the ELM327 take.

When I attempt to send AT commands to the ELM327 device the I get a response like `A?TZ?>`. After much testing I have been able to get all of my commands to work but only if I follow the next steps exactly:

1. Unplug the Arduino and let it power down.
2. Plug the Arduino back in and open the Serial monitor and send whatever command I want AT or PID such as `ATZ` or `010C`.
3. Wait until the HC05 connects to the ELM327 device and the first response that I get back will be correct such as a hex number for RPM.

Any following attempts at sending PID codes will return NODATA.
I have verified that both of the devices work independently of each other using the Bluetooth Serial Monitor app. I can send endless AT or PID codes to the ELM327 from my phone and I get the appropriate response. I have a feeling that it is an issue with either the end characters or with the way the data is being sent across the Serial line.

I would be happy to provide any additional information needed.

Thank you.

Comment: which part of your post is about arduino? ... the sensor is responding with a message

Comment: I am wondering if there is something going on with the way I am using Arduino's Software Serial that is making my inputs unable to be read properly by the ELM327 device when passed through the HC05. Apologies for not clarifying on what the problem is.

Comment: if the HC05 is sending you clear, readable messages, then the problem is not the arduino